# Query for returning a tree like structure in neo4j checking membership relationships

Tags: neo4j

I need a neo4j query for the use case below and I need it to return the “path”.

Something like this but considering the following premises

```
MATCH (topParent:Space {slug: “S1-1-1X”})
MATCH path = (topParent)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(child:Space)
RETURN path;
```

Please see the illustration below for reference.  I have this graph where a space can have subspaces in a hierarchy (circles). Also the spaces can have privacy open or privacy private (red circle) and each space can have “member_of” relationships with role manager (square) or member (triangle).

If the role is “manager” the user can see the whole tree below that space no matter the privacy level.

If the role is “member” it can see all “open” spaces below that membership.

Also if the top space is “open” any user can see any open subspaces.

[image: Neo4j graph structure]

Comment: 1. What is a "user", and how is it related to "spaces", "roles", etc.? 2. Is 'if the top space is “open” any user can see any open subspaces' just saying that the default role is "member", or is it saying something else?

Comment: @cybersam 1. users are nodes that relate with spaces by the "member_of" relationship with an attribute "role" that can be either "member" or "manager". 2. A user may not be a "member_of" a space and still be able to see it if the space privacy is open and is a "member_of" any parent space above. Note, privacy is an attribute on the space node

Comment: @Makarov Are you and "@Lorenz" working together? In any case, there are still holes in the description of the user case. But it is at least bit clearer now.

Is the query supposed to be provided with a user (or some property value that identifies the user), and output all the paths the user can take, starting with its related role?

Comment: @cybersam yes we work together. The graph has basically 2 types of nodes Spaces and Users, and 2 relationships Space to Space called PARENT_OF and User to Space called MEMBER_OF
User has a username identifier, Space has a slug identifier and a privacy attribute.
MEMBER_OF has role attribute "manager or "member"
In the image provided, triangles and squares are both User nodes but with different role, A User MEMBER_OF a Space with role "manager" can see the whole tree below that relationship
A User MEMBER_OF a Space with role "member" can only see the spaces below that are "open"

Comment: OK, thanks for more details. But what is the desired query supposed to do, what is the desired output, and are you providing any inputs?

Comment: @cybersam The query has two inputs User username and Top space slug, The idea of the query is to return the tree from the top space down to its subspaces but only those subspaces that the user can see given his memberships to the spaces of the tree, so User A can have a tree of X number of spaces and User B can have a tree of Y number of spaces all starting from the top level space, So in the image provided, square can see the entire tree, Triangle can also see the entire tree assuming top level is open, but any other user won't see the "red" space and it children because that one is private.

Comment: @Makarov You said a member of a space 'with role "member" can only see the spaces **below** that are "open"'. In the illustration, the triangle user is a member of a private (non-open) space. Since that space is not open, is the the triangle user nevertheless allowed to see that space (and its open descendents)? In other words, did you mean "at and below" instead of "below"?

Comment: @Makarov And in general, if user U is a member of the root of a subtree that contains a private space P that has open children, is U allowed to see the children of P but not P itself? And if so, what is the resulting "path" supposed to look like -- are we supposed to just pretend that the children of P are actually the children of the parent of P?

Comment: @cybersam 1. Yes at and below, 2. If U is a member of a root subtree that contains a private space P, the member can't see the P space or its descendants,

Answer (score 0):

In your example you use something called "var length relationships" (i.e. [:PARENT_OF*]). To solve your problem I would instead use something called Quantified Path Patterns, which was introduced in Neo4j 5.8.0.

But first of all, let me make sure I understand your data model. I have tried to recreate your graph like this (I made some assumptions for some of the properties you didn't describe in detail):

```
CREATE (manager:Role {role:"Manager"})
CREATE (member:Role {role:"Member"})
CREATE (s1:Space {slug:"S1-1-1X", open:true})
CREATE (s2:Space {open:false})
CREATE (s3:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s4:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s5:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s6:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s7:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s8:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s9:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s10:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s11:Space {open:true})
CREATE (s1)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s2)
CREATE (s2)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s3)
CREATE (s2)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s4)
CREATE (s2)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s5)
CREATE (s1)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s6)
CREATE (s1)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s7)
CREATE (s7)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s8)
CREATE (s7)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s9)
CREATE (s8)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s10)
CREATE (s8)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s11)
CREATE (s2)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(member)
CREATE (s1)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(manager)
```

This gives a graph that looks like this (and seem to resemble your sketch):
[image]

Now the query, using Quantified Path Patterns, could look something like this. Not sure if this would do exactly what you aim for, but hopefully you can tweak it to get what you want:

```
MATCH (topParent:Space {slug: "S1-1-1X"})
MATCH path = ((topParent)((s1:Space WHERE s1.open OR (topParent)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(:Role {role:"Manager"}))-[:PARENT_OF]->(s2:Space))+)
RETURN path
```

The + in the end means that the path before can be repeated 1 to many times. You can replace the + with {0,5} for 0 to 5 times or {5} for exactly 5 times.

You can read more on Quantified Path Patterns here:

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/concepts/#quantified-path-patterns

Comment: Our graph is a little different, Member and Manager are actually Users and the MEMBER_OF relationship has an attribute role.
I modify a little but the query like this following you example:
MATCH (topParent:Space {slug: "vflccy"})
MATCH path = ((topParent)((s1:Space WHERE s1.privacy_level = "open" OR (topParent)<-[:MEMBER_OF{role: "manager"}]-(:User {username:"justsimon"}))-[:PARENT_OF]->(s2:Space))+)
RETURN path

But as far as I can tell, the membership is only being checked on the top parent right? I need to check it on all the parents of each subspace

Comment: @Makarov Would it work if you just change `OR (topParent)<-[:MEMBER_OF{role: "manager"}]-` to `OR NOT (s1)<-[:MEMBER_OF{role: "member"}]-`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using ORDPATH, a concatenated bit string sorting hierarchically. You merely need an integer collection (e.g., node ids) during path traversals and then call the user defined function describes here:

https://www.wai.md/post/ordpath-computing-genealogy-descendancy-trees

If you are looking for visualizations, D3 would be one option.